# Upgrade-Insecure-Requests as an alternative for HSTS

Tags: tls, http, hsts

I have seen that websites automatically transform HTTP requests into HTTPS without the HTTP Strict Transport Security (HSTS) Header.

So does the following line in the request fully alleviate the need for HSTS?

```
Content-Security-Policy: upgrade-insecure-requests;
```

Comment: What is your question?

Answer (score 11, accepted):

From [MDN](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/HTTP/Headers/Content-Security-Policy/upgrade-insecure-requests):

> The `upgrade-insecure-requests` directive will not ensure that users
>   visiting your site via links on third-party sites will be upgraded to
>   HTTPS for the top-level navigation and thus does not replace the
>   Strict-Transport-Security (HSTS) header, which should still be set
>   with an appropriate max-age to ensure that users are not subject to
>   SSL stripping attacks.

Answer (score 5):

`upgrade-insecure-requests` upgrades any http request to https when the page is loaded over https. This helps to avoid mixed content issue but will not force the page to be loaded over secure schema.

More details can be found on https://scotthelme.co.uk/migrating-from-http-to-https-ease-the-pain-with-csp-and-hsts/

Answer (score 3):

They do different things. `Content-Security-Policy: upgrade-insecure-requests` affects your page's resources for only a single session, including things linked to on other domains. HSTS affects your own domain, and the user's browser remembers it for longer than a single session.

Comment: _your_ and _your_ do not refer to the same person. If you set the HSTS header for _your_ own domain, requests from visitors will be upgraded and _their_ browser will remember to do this for all _their subsequent requests to any resource on your domain, for a specified max-age.

Comment: Oh yeah I used one too many "your"s. I've tweaked the wording now.